# Dotted text in uilabel in ios

Tags: ios, ios7, uilabel

I need to show the score in `UILabel` in the below format. Is it possible ?
I want to show like dotted numbers in `UILabel`. The below link is the example image.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There a couple of different ways.  You can go through the trouble to construct your own numbers from smaller images.  You could create images in png files and load them.  Some people sell scoreboard fonts (probably easiest).

But you are not going to get a default behavior from Apple to do that.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It will be not as easy as you maybe want to be, but I can give you following options.
As MinnesotaSteve mentioned, you could use images, but I think it is kind of hack solution.
Also with the font you could get the desired look, but you are going to have problems to map the background dots on the font dots ...

I would suggest you trying to use CALayers with the border dash pattern.
Then you can define your custom layers for all the possible numbers 0 - 9, to get the effect.

But if you want just dotted text not matching the background, you can use the font solution.